# Process page after form data validation

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a donation page I am working on. After filling out the form, submit it is pressed, sends data to a php page, and either returns html to be displayed in a modal, or uses javascript to allow the page to be submitted.  Because of the asyncronous nature of javascript, I'm not sure how to fix this.  When I click submit with valid data, it checks the data, switches the boolean to true, but does not submit as it was checked before the data was returned.

This web page is also running in wordpress.

Here is the code.

```
var check = 0;
function noError(){
    check = 1;
}

jQuery('#donateform').submit(function() {
    jQuery.post(
        'validate.php', 
        jQuery("#donateform").serialize(), 
        function(data) {
            jQuery('#overlay_msg').html(data);
        }
    );

    if(check != 1)
        event.preventDefault();
    else
        self.submit();
});
```

In `validate.php` it calls

```
function noError() {
    check = 1;
}
```

If the data is valid.

I will keep looking into it.

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you to make the validate.php to return json data in place of a function, and to check that data when you receive it in place of printing it with jQuery('#overlay_msg').html(data);

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if i understand completely but if your problem is order of process: IE, click submit, validate, then actually submit via ajax then i would suggest the following.

replace the submit type input with a button

when this is clicked have it run your validation, if validation passes then have that function submit the form via ajax for you

html

```
<button type="button" id="submitButton">submit</button>

$('#submitButton').click(function(){
//run validation
if (validate == true){
ajaxSubmitFunction();
}
});

ajaxSubmitFunction(){
//run your ajax.
}
```

This has cleared a lot of headaches for me when validating and then submitting forms via ajax